# I need serious help in changing the vaue of a column within the same column by going 2 rows up and changing the value

Tags: replace, while-loop, row, common-table-expression

I am a DBA of 7 months so please bear with me. I am needing to write a code that will find a particular ProductIdentifier. When this particular ProductIdentifier is found, 1. I need to grab this ProductIdentifier. 2. I need to go 2 rows up and place that ProductIdentifier in the field that is 2 rows above it.

Here is my code(everything is sorted properly already in this table)

SELECT
SipID,
SaleInvoiceID,
AssociationNumber,
Priority,
TotalPrice,
TotalCost,
SerialNumber,
ContractNumber,
ActivatedThroughPAW,
DateCreatedatMidnight,
ReceivedDate,
InvoiceIDByStore,
Location,
ProductIdentifier,
Description,
ShortDescription,
CategoryName,
RevenueStreamID,
RevenueType

FROM REVISEDTABLE.

I will better show you what needs to be done  ![enter image description here][1]

ProductIdentifier
AWUPG2001RGP   -- replace this product identifier with the 'AWRPNS000%'
POSC0021PRW
AWRPNS000343 --take this product identifier

What I need for this code to do is this: whenever I find any ProductIdentifier like 'AWRPNS000%', I need for the query to take this and go 2 rows up and replace whatever ProductIdentifier is in this with 'AWRPNS000%'. I then need to insert the results into a table. I believe the best thing to do is to select the ProductIdentifier row again and give it an alias. This will be the row that I need to transform. I can then do a comparison to see if things worked out. I do not know how to write the code to do the actual grabbing of the ProductIdentifier and going up 2 rows and replacing it, so any help or input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So what does two rows up mean. Why is it two rows up.

e.g.

```
ID Class Type Date
1  1     2    20/12/2012
2  1     2    21/12/2012
3  1     2    22/12/2012 *
```

ie yes ID is two rows up but that's because The records are in ID and date order and there are at least three of them.

If you can come up with that rule e.g.

```
Select * From SomeTable Where Class = 1 and Type = 2 And Date = 20/12/2012
```

Then all your problems go away...

Comment: I am in charge of restructuring our SalesImport Process. The AWRPNS% Is associated with a phone. There are other associations with phones, but this is an association from the actual physical invoice for just an outright sale of a phone. There is a priority to this. This process was done in Filemaker, but I am in charge of redoing this process in SQL. In other words, this process must be done this way. In Filemaker, there is a script that says when the 'AWRPNS000%' is found, go up 2 rows and change the product identifier. I believe I will need either a while loop or cte to do this.

Comment: If you could use a CTE, you'd be able to answer the above. Cursor or while loop might do it, but messy, very very messy.

Comment: Ok. I have the code that I am using in the question that I posted. I wrote this but it does not work: <br> WITH ctea (rowID, ProductIdentifier) AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceIDByStore) AS rowID, ProductIdentifier FROM REVISEDTABLE AS tn) SELECT ProductIdentifier, CASE WHEN ctea.ProductIdentifier Like 'AWRPNS0003%'
THEN ( SELECT ctea.ProductIdentifier  
FROM ctea AS ctea2 
WHERE ctea2.rowID = ctea.rowID + 2)
 ELSE ctea.ProductIdentifier 
END as ProdIDChange from ctea

Comment: Can't even start to help you without knowing why the record you want to change is two rows up. It's only two rows up because of the order the data is in the selection it's two rows up in. Change the way it's ordered , it isn't two rows up anymore is it...